# What test should I use to check whether these two groups are statistically different?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution

I am writing my dissertation on the impact of COVID-19 restrictions on air quality.

I am comparing air quality data from the first fourth months (January, February, March, and April) of 2020 with data that has been averaged from the last 3 years (2017, 2018, 2019) within the same months.

So I have data for 2020 Jan, Feb, March, April and averaged data from the last 3 years (also Jan, Feb, March, April).

I want to see whether there is a statistically significant difference between those two time categories (2020 and 'pre-2020' so to speak). So I checked whether the data is normally distributed using Shapiro-Wilk.

My 'pre-2020' data is normally distributed for all 4 months
My 2020 data is normally distributed for January, March, April but February is **not** normally distributed.

I am therefore confused about which (Wilcoxon Signed or dependent t-test or other) test to do from here.

- side note: i'm assuming the previous years air quality affects the subsequent years', and therefore the two categories are not independent

Comment: Whether these data have normal distributions is irrelevant.  Do you have only monthly averages or do you have data obtained over shorter time periods?  Often, for instance, air quality stations are monitored at least daily.

Comment: Hi, yes my data is daily. I haven't averaged the monthly data. For example, I did average the data for 01/01/17, 01/01/18, and 01/01/19 and that averaged value represents 01/01 in my 'pre-2020' category. Why is it irrelevant if the data have normal distributions if I my ask?

Comment: Few statistical tests--and almost no tests of paired data--assume or require normality of the individual data.  What matters is the sampling distribution of the test statistic, not the data distribution.  Furthermore, it is rarely valid to select your procedure for analyzing data based on a formal preliminary distributional test (unless you adjust the subsequent p-values to account for that).  Finally, it's likely the most pressing issue for you to deal with will be the serial correlation of the daily data: you appear to have a problem in time series analysis.

Comment: Ah okay - I was assuming the distribution was important because that's an assumption that should be met to determine whether or not a certain test is the right one? Also could you please expand on this, "serial correlation of the daily data: you appear to have a problem in time series analysis."? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/time-series/info.

Comment: Thanks for the resource. I'm still wondering as to what test is best to perform? I'm leaning towards Paired t-test, as the groups are related & there is mostly normal distribution, with the exception of February

Comment: A t-test is unlikely to be appropriate due to the expected correlations among the data.  Consider beginning with an exploratory analysis where you visually compare plots of the time series data.  (Doing this first with simulated data will protect you from possible charges of "data snooping.")  There's nothing like *looking* at data to stimulate ideas about how to analyze them.

Comment: Okay I'll look into that! Thanks @whuber, I appreciate all your help!